# How to retrieve passwords from a database

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2, bcrypt

I am building a registration system for my web application wherein users provide a username and a password. This data is stored in a `postgresql` database. I am using bcrypt to generate a salted hash of the user entered password as follows

```
import bcrypt
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(PasswordFromWebForm.encode('UTF-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
```

This creates a salted password that looks something like this - `b'$2b$12$GskbcRCMFHGuXumrNt3FLO'`

I am storing this value in a `postgresql` database. Next, when a user tries to login to the system, I want to verify his/her credentials. To do this, I intend to do something along the lines of -

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=me")
cur = conn.cursor()

saltedpassword = cur.execute("SELECT saltedpassword FROM test WHERE loginid = %s", (LoginIDFromWebForm,))

if bcrypt.hashpw(PasswordFromWebForm.encode('UTF-8'), saltedpassword) == saltedpassword:
    print("Success")
```

This does not work. It throws the following `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing` error.

I suspect that this error is because the variable `saltedpassword` stores the value as a string like this `"b'$2b$12$GskbcRCMFHGuXumrNt3FLO'"` instead of just plain `b'$2b$12$GskbcRCMFHGuXumrNt3FLO'` (Notice the quotes enclosing the salted password in the former)

How do I get around this problem? What is the best way to store the salted hashed password in a database and how do I go about retrieving it when needed for verification? Apologies for the rather longish question  - please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`psycopg2` stores Unicode *text*, you must decode the salted password before inserting into the database:

```
 cur.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES (%s, %s)",
             (LoginIDFromWebForm,  saltedpassword.decode('ascii')))
```

This prevents the `str()` conversion being inserted instead (giving you `"b'....'"` in the database).

Next, when querying `saltedpassword` is not a string, because `cursor.execute()` does not return the results; it returns `None` instead.

You'll need to [fetch the result row](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchone):

```
cur.execute("SELECT saltedpassword FROM test WHERE loginid = %s", (LoginIDFromWebForm,))
row = cur.fetchone()
if not row:
    # No such login ID, handle accordingly
saltedpassword =  row[0].encode('ascii')
```

Since rows contain Unicode text, you need to first encode to a bytestring before passing it to `bcrypt`. You also want to use the `bcrypt.checkpw()` function to check the password:

```
if bcrypt.checkpw(PasswordFromWebForm.encode('UTF-8'), saltedpassword):
    print("Success")
```

`bcrypt.checkpw()` avoids [timing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) when comparing strings, something your code is vulnerable to.

Comment: In fairness, the bcrypt docs check the password using `if bcrypt.hashpw(password, hashed) == hashed` - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/2.0.0

Comment: @slim: see the updated documentation for bcrypt 3:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/3.1.2, `checkpw()` was added in 3.1.0.

Comment: Ah yes, just seen that :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks, that solved it. But I did not completely understand why we are converting `b'$2b$12$GskbcRCMFHGuXumrNt3FLO'` which I think is Unicode to ascii before storin it in the db

Comment: No, that's a bytes value (the `b` prefix is an important clue there).